# Windows Authenticated url in UIWebView no response, no error, request spinning indefinitely - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, windows, webview, xamarin.ios, windows-authentication

I am trying to load windows authenticated url in UIWebView. Below is my code.

```
public override void WillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge(NSUrlConnection connection, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge)
        {
            if (challenge.ProtectionSpace.AuthenticationMethod == NSUrlProtectionSpace.AuthenticationMethodNTLM)
            {
                if (challenge.PreviousFailureCount > 0)
                {
                    challenge.Sender.CancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge);
                }
                else
                {
                    var credentialSpace = new NSUrlProtectionSpace("http://authenticatedurl.com", 80, "http", "http://authenticatedurl.com", "NTLM");
                    NSUrlCredentialStorage credentialStorage = NSUrlCredentialStorage.SharedCredentialStorage;
                    var credential = new NSUrlCredential ("username", "password", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession);
                    credentialStorage.SetDefaultCredential (credential, credentialSpace);
                    connection.UseCredential (credential, challenge);
                    connection.PerformDefaultHandling (challenge);
                    isAuthenticated = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

above delegate is called and its successfully executing UserCredential without any error, but website is not loaded. Its keep on spinning for hours. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> var credentialSpace = new
>   NSUrlProtectionSpace("http://authenticatedurl.com", 80, "http",
>   "http://authenticatedurl.com", "NTLM");

try this,

> var credentialSpace = new
>   NSUrlProtectionSpace("authenticatedurl.com", 80, "http",
>   "authenticatedurl.com", "NTLM");

It should work !